# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

In my React Native project, I have such kind of error: ***Text strings must be rendered within a Text***
This is my project https://snack.expo.io/@jasurkurbanov/updated2
Interesting point is that I can run it on the web, but when I run it on my phone it is showing this error. Can anyone review my code and tell what is problem

Comment: Check line 35, you have some extra whitespace between the `<View>` start tag and the content.

Comment: Bro thank you. Write it on answers. I will highlight it as answer

Comment: Tell me how why extra space also influence so much ?

Comment: can you try this? https://snack.expo.io/r1oYy7YjB

Comment: bro problem is solved by Jeff Mercado, I guess you also found this. Thank you by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whitespace matters here it seems in a native app.

```
/* line 35 */ <View> {replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(item.value)
```

Your view element contains text (the space). You need to remove it.

I don't know for sure, I think it's because when it's all parsed out, it's considered significant whitepsace (it's on the same line as some non-whitepsace content). So it's treated as mixed content (text and code).

It would compile to something like this:

```
React.createElement('View', {}, ' ', replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(item.value) ? ...)
```

Personally I would have expected it to trim all leading and trailing whitespace like it usually does but I guess not.

Comment: It means in react native, {space} considered as <Text> component?

Comment: Why then it displayed on web?

Comment: In a browser, the whitespace doesn't matter because the browser won't care. I suspect that for a native app, every element needs to be wrapped in some native component, so you can't have random text in your jsx file. Similar to how XML is in some ways.

Comment: Got it ! Thank you